# How to put into a tuple?

Tags: python, dictionary, append, tuples

I have a dictionary of :

```
dict1 = {
  1: {'red': 5, 'blue': 7}, 
  2: {'red': 2, 'blue': 6, 'yellow': 9}, 
  3: {'red': 8, 'yellow': 4}
}
```

How would I print:

```
((1,2)(2,3)(3,2))
```

with the keys being the first key terms in dict1, and the value is how many colors in each?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need collect the key and length of value(dictionary) into a tuple of tuples:

```
>>> tuple((k, len(v)) for k, v in dict1.items())
((1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 2))
```

You can iterate the key and value of a dictionary with [`dict.items()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `zip` as follows:

```
>>> tuple(zip(dict1.keys(), map(len, dict1.values())))
((1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 2))
```

Comment: You don't need to call `.keys()` here: `tuple(zip(dict1, map(len, dict1.values())))`. However, it might be better for clarity to include it.